# Como tirar background-color do padding?

Tags: css, html

Estou utilizando o Bootstrap 3 e tenho uma div assim:

```html
<li class="col-md-3">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Example" />
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; ">
        <span style="position: absolute; widht: 100%; height: 100%; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; background-color: #000">
            <p>Teste</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Clique Aqui</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Queria que esse `span` tivesse o background apenas no padding, como tem na col-md-3, para que o background ficasse apenas na imagem.

Tentei algumas formas mas não consegui, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Já tentou usar bordas? border-left: 15px; border-right: 15px; border-color: solid #000;

Comment: @xmdenis tentei aqui agora mas, não resolveu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `padding` é um espaço dentro do `container`, ou seja, se você tem uma cor de fundo ela será apresentada. Acredito que não seja possível retirar a cor de fundo apenas de uma parte.

Mas como disse o `@xmdenis` use bordas ou use `margin`.

```
     <span style="position: absolute; widht: 100%; height: 100%; border-left: 15px solid #000; border-right: 15px solid #000;">
        <p>Teste</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Clique Aqui</button>
    </span>
```

Comment: isso me resolveu :D

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim amigo:

CSS:

```
div {
    padding:50px;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(240, 255, 40, 1) 0%, rgba(240, 255, 40, 1) 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(240, 40, 40, 1) 0%, rgba(240, 40, 40, 1) 100%);
    background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
}
```